# Setting WPF Button Style Programmatically

Tags: wpf, xaml, resourcedictionary

I have the below style:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <Style x:Key="RoundCorner" TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
        <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Center"/>
        <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Center"/>
        <Setter Property="Padding" Value="1"/>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                    <Border CornerRadius="0,0,4,4" BorderBrush="black" 
     BorderThickness="1,0,1,1" >
                        <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                            VerticalAlignment="Center"
                            Margin="1"></ContentPresenter>
                    </Border>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
        <Setter Property="LayoutTransform">
            <Setter.Value>
                <RotateTransform CenterX="0.5" CenterY="0.5" Angle="270" />
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</Window.Resources>
```

I am setting it to a button like this

```
<Button x:Name="btn_bfx" ToolTip="BreakFix" Content="BFX" Click="btn_bfx_Click" Height="30" Width="40" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" ></Button>
```

In constructor I am setting the style like :

```
btn_bfx.Style = this.Resources["RoundCorner"] as Style;
```

later based on some condition I would like to change the style.

The code is as below:

```
Style oldStyle = FindResource("RoundCorner") as Style;
Style newStyle = new Style();
newStyle.BasedOn = oldStyle;
newStyle.TargetType = typeof(Button);
foreach (var setter in oldStyle.Setters.ToList())
{
    newStyle.Setters.Add(setter);
}
newStyle.Setters.Add(new Setter(BackgroundProperty, Brushes.CadetBlue));
btn_bfx.Style = newStyle;
```

The newStyle is just adding background color to the oldStyle. But this new style is not being applied. I am still getting the style without background color.

Comment: not an anwer, but if you define the new style in XAML too it would be much easier to write and read than in code behind.

Comment: I tried defining the style in XAML first and then just setting like this btn_bfx.Style = FindResource("RoundCornerBackground") as Style; It also did not work.

Comment: This can be done without code behind in the style using data triggers. If you bind the data trigger to a property representing your change in condition then use the setters within the trigger to make your changes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your style re-writes the Button's `ControlTemplate`, so the Background color is no longer used.

In the ControlTemplate, add a Background property to the Border like this

```
<Border CornerRadius="0,0,4,4" BorderBrush="black" BorderThickness="1,0,1,1" 
    Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
```

Then it will pick up whatever background you set.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done without code behind in the style using data triggers. If you bind the data trigger to a property representing your change in condition then use the setters within the trigger to make your changes. For example:

```
<Button>
                    <Button.Style>
                        <Style TargetType="Button">
                            <Setter Property="Background" Value="White"></Setter>
                            <Style.Triggers>
                                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding condition}" Value="True">
                                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Black"></Setter>
                                </DataTrigger>
                            </Style.Triggers>
                        </Style>
                    </Button.Style>
                </Button>
```

This to me is easier and more tidy than the way you are trying to adjust the style. It keeps it all in one place instead of half in XAML and half in code behind.

Comment: Hi. I am not using MVVM as it is just a simple 1 window project which fetches some data from user and updates some table through a WEB API.  My intension is the by changing background color the user will have a visual feedback of the option he has selected. So on the click of the button I was trying to change background color. That's it.